# Switch MediaView doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

Why isn't this code working and can someone give me a solution maybe?

Playing the first Movie works well, but after clicking the `Button` I lose my `MediaView` and the next Video isn't played.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class VideoTest extends Application{

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private MediaView view;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox box = new HBox();
        player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("file:///C:/path/to/file"));
        view = new MediaView();
        view.setMediaPlayer(player);
        player.play();

        Button button = new Button("Next");
        button.setOnAction(e->{
            player.stop();
            player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("file:///C:/path/to/file"));
            view = new MediaView(player);
            player.play();
        });

        box.getChildren().addAll(view,button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box,700,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add new media view to the scene, so you will never see it.

Instead of create a new media view, just set the new player into your existing media view (which you have already attached to the scene).

```
button.setOnAction(e->{
    player.stop();
    player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv"));
    view.setMediaPlayer(player);
    player.play();
});
```